# openCV face detection

Tags: python, opencv

This is a simple code for face detection using openCV :

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("one.jpg")
hc = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")
faces = hc.detectMultiScale(img)

for face in faces:
  print 'inside for loop ! '
  cv2.rectangle(img, (face[0], face[1]), (face[0] + face[2], face[0] + face[3]), (255,     0, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Face", img)
if cv2.waitKey(5000) == 27:
  cv2.destroyWindow("Face")
cv2.imwrite("two.jpg", img)
```

but when I run this code, the final image displayed ie two.jpg is the same as given in input   ie one.jpg! without any face being detected.. the code inside the for loop is never executed ... why is it so ? Are there any changes which I should make in the code ?

[this is the image I am giving as one.jpg & the final image ie two.jpg also looks the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9PFv.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried executing the code line by line and checking whether `faces` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems none of the faces in the image you use have been detected (in which case, the for loop will not be executed). you can:

1. Use an image that has an easier-to-detect (large, no glasses) face.
2. Step through the code using a debugger (I don't know how to do this in Python, but it should be easier to find out)
3. Check the following attributes of faces
   a. size
   b. location coordinates of each face if detected.